# How do I import Microsoft Visual Foxpro tables into Microsoft Access 2007?

Tags: ms-access, webrick

From what I understand, I can no longer use ODBC to connect to Visual Foxpro 9 tables in Microsoft Access 2007.  I see that I need to connect using OLE DB.  I downloaded the Visual Foxpro provider, but I haven't found the instructions to complete my link or import from within Access.  Does anyone have an answer?

Comment: Where did you get the idea that you couldn't use ODBC?

Answer (score 3):

Found It. Microsoft dropped the ODBC driver but this one worked for me. XP SP2
http://www.topol.eu/articles/download%20odbc

Comment: I hope no one needs to be warned about downloading a *driver* from some random website...

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there is a way to [use odbc](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/824264)

Answer (score 0):

The ODBC drivers for FoxPro tables are not included with later versions of Access.

The simple solution is to download the ODBC drivers for FoxPro.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vfoxpro/bb190233.aspx

Once you do the above, then you can use the standard import options from access to pull the data in, and in fact you can actually link to the table and edit the data from access without having to import.

In fact you can use the link provided by Jeff, but just have to install the above driver first.

Also the above driver supports the so called free tables. That’s when a database was considered a directory, and each dBase file place inside the directory would appear as a table that exists in a given database (thus a database was essentially a folder with files for each table).

When the windows select data source dialogue comes up, you’ll have to click on a machine data source, and they are you’ll see a choice of two drivers that you just installed.  Just pick the visual Foxpro database driver.

Simply install the above ODBC driver, then use external data tab on the ribbon, and choose ODBC, the wizard will start, and you can link or import that visual FoxPro Data.

As a side note, then above link is a little bit confusing, you want to scroll down a little bit and choose the MSI file…not the first download choice.

Comment: The *ODBC* drivers for FoxPro were *never* included with Access. It was an installable ISAM driver that was included, just like for dBase, which is very different from ODBC.